# jquery select2 remove arrow like multiselect input

Tags: css, jquery-select2-4

I'm using last version of select2 plugin (4.0.2) and I'd like to remove arrow from my single select like multiselect input style.
I tried to edit the css where there are arrow's element but without success.
Can someone tell me how can I do? 
Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Do you want just to remove the arrow?

try this:

```
$('b[role="presentation"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add this before closing the head tag on your page.

```
<style>
.select2-selection__arrow b{
    display:none !important;
}
</style>
```

This will not screw up anything like width and all. It just won't show that arrow.